# SSL Error while building Python 2.7.18 from source

Tags: python-2.7, ssl

```
Exception in thread Thread-213:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 245, in run
    asyncore.loop(timeout=0.1, count=1)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 220, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 156, in poll
    read(obj)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 87, in read
    obj.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 83, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 331, in handle_read_event
    super(SSLConnection, self).handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 449, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 119, in handle_read
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 115, in handle_read
    data = self.recv (self.ac_in_buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 353, in recv
    return super(SSLConnection, self).recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 387, in recv
    data = self.socket.recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 754, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 641, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_TKT_NYV] unexpected eof while reading (_ssl.c:1946)

Exception in thread Thread-214:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 245, in run
    asyncore.loop(timeout=0.1, count=1)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 220, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 156, in poll
    read(obj)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 87, in read
    obj.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 83, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 331, in handle_read_event
    super(SSLConnection, self).handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 449, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 119, in handle_read
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 115, in handle_read
    data = self.recv (self.ac_in_buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 353, in recv
    return super(SSLConnection, self).recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 387, in recv
    data = self.socket.recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 754, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 641, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 0] Error

Exception in thread Thread-215:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 245, in run
    asyncore.loop(timeout=0.1, count=1)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 220, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 156, in poll
    read(obj)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 87, in read
    obj.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 83, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 331, in handle_read_event
    super(SSLConnection, self).handle_read_event()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 449, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 119, in handle_read
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asynchat.py", line 115, in handle_read
    data = self.recv (self.ac_in_buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/test/test_ftplib.py", line 353, in recv
    return super(SSLConnection, self).recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/asyncore.py", line 387, in recv
    data = self.socket.recv(buffer_size)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 754, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/home/trevor/Python-2.7.18/Lib/ssl.py", line 641, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 0] Error
```

I am facing the above error while compiling Python2.7.18 from source files. How can I fix the SSL issue? I looked at some GitHub issues, but they didn't work. Are there any patches that need to be applied before the build?

I tried installing Pyenv, and it installs Python 2.7.18 correctly without any errors, but I am facing environment specific issues on Pyenv.

**OS**:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**OpenSSL Version** : `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`

**Build Commands**:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j 9
```

**Python 2.7.18 Source Code**: `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz`

**GCC and Kernel Versions**:
`Linux version 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023`

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Post the build command, , *OpenSSL* version and so on.

Comment: @CristiFati, added details you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error - I had to downgrade to `openssl-1.1.1` and then it compiled. Also don't forget `zlib-1.1.3`+!